# Wordpress insert media stopped working

Tags: file-upload, wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite installation that worked fine about 1 year but now, suddenly I can't use media for my posts. I can upload them and they show up in library, but when I want to insert them in a post, I see just a blank screen and any upload attempt in that frame fails.
Do you have any idea about this problem or how could I trace it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this step to fix that issue ....

1 .deactivate all plugin and try to upload media again if its work mean there is conflict in plugin
2 .update wordpress to latest version if already a latest version please try to re-update them
3 . debug wordpress so you can find exact issue http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I had deactivated all plugins and it didn't help.

Comment: I think it could be a server config problem as @user2500469 said, cause I didn't change anything recently and Wordpress is up to date.

Comment: It had shown nothing. I even tried to enable logging the errors but that showed nothing too.

Comment: Well, I replaced old wp-admin and wp-includes and in update section, update message showed up. I updated wordpress to 3.5.1 (My Wordpress version was alread 3.5.1) and it seems the problem has gone. Thank you @Sonu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my host provider automatically enabled Google's Pagespeed Service optimization. Apparently it doesn't like the WordPress images but once I contacted them, they turned it off and everything started working fine again. You might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove everything before starting php tag(which is present in the starting of every wordpress's php file) in functions.php and if you are included(require) other php files in it than also do the same in each of php file.

this is for theme development only.